# Undefined Reference at Linking in Static Git Build

Tags: linux, git, gcc, linker, makefile

I'm trying to install git on a shared server (with no root access or compiler) by building it statically on my own machine (running Arch Linux) with the same processor architecture (x86_64) as the server, as explained in [this guide](http://www.lyraphase.com/wp/projects/how-to-build-git-for-a-host-with-no-compiler/).

When I ran `make`, I always got these errors and a failure:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_func':
(.text+0x364): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_func':
(.text+0x422): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_var':
(.text+0x494): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_var':
(.text+0x552): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_load':
(.text+0x5c2): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_load':
(.text+0x62d): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_load':
(.text+0x65a): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_pathbyaddr':
(.text+0x6ef): undefined reference to `dladdr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_pathbyaddr':
(.text+0x749): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_unload':
(.text+0x7aa): undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [git-imap-send] Error 1
```

Comment: Logs that do not show the actual commands are not useful. You should use `make V=1` next time. Also, note that warnings about static linking and glibc. Your binary may not work on different systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally discovered [a different guide](http://en.newinstance.it/2011/02/27/how-to-create-a-statically-linked-version-of-git-binaries/), which advised running a slightly different .configure command. What ended up working for me was [this guide](http://www.lyraphase.com/wp/projects/how-to-build-git-for-a-host-with-no-compiler/), with the exception of running

`$ ./configure --prefix=/home/myuser/git-static CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -static" NO_OPENSSL=1 NO_CURL=1`

in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates it can't find the definition of

```
dlclose
dlerror
dleopen
```

You need to make sure your makefile has `-ldl` when link the application.

Comment: I'd previously attempted adding


    LDFLAGS=-ldl


, but I got the same result.

Comment: Yup, I see that but is it in your makefile?

Answer (score 0):

`LDFLAGS` are for the linker flags. `LIBS` are for the linked libraries. Confusing them is not usually a problem, but in the case of static libs or when the linker has the `--as-needed` option enabled the order of libraries matters and any `-l` passed before libs that use it will be ignored.